# rails error from old version rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am try to do as this tutorial does

```
http://www.noupe.com/ajax/create-a-simple-twitter-app.html
```

,but when try to test this simple rails, it's  give me some error. is any one know ho to fix it?

```
< %= render :partial => "message_form" %> < %= render :partial => @posts %>
```

[image]

Comment: paste the stack trace of the error please

Comment: hi,thanks. but I am new to rails. I dont know how to do it

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: Hi,I just fix it.but new problem found it. I am still can not post something.it's display some thing from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps take out the space between < and %=

Comment: but I am still can not post something.it's display some thing from the database.